# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED on Android 6 (API 23)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to deploy my app (in debug/release) on Android 6 (API 23) but on Android 8 (API 26) and Android 9 (API 28) everything works fine. There is a INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error in output.

**Output:**

> Detecting installed packages...
>
> Copying application to device...
>
> 90% ... 21184kb of 23527kb copied
>
> 100% ... 23527kb of 23527kb copied
>
> ADB0000:  Deployment failed Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException:
>   Unexpected install output:        pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.companyname.appname-Signed.apk Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] 
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in E:\A_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 345
>      at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task`1 t) in E:\A\_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line 753
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> ADB0010: Unexpected install output:      pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.companyname.appname-Signed.apk Failure
>   [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
>
> at
>   Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String
>   output, String packageName) in
>   E:\A_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line
>   345    at
>   Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass95_0.b__0(Task`1
>   t) in
>   E:\A\_work\275\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:line
>   753    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke() 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Done building project
>   "AppNameInCamelCase.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED. 
>   Blockquote

Build FAILED.

> 2>Deployment failed to Samsung SM-G800F.
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

**Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall" android:versionName="X.X.x" android:versionCode="XXXYYY">
       <!--Target SDK version should be 25+ in order to ask for permissions in popups.-->
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
       <!--Permissions which are requested via popup.-->
       <!--For logging and data writing.-->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <!--For picking photo.-->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <!--For location-->
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
       <!--Permissions granted during installation.-->
       <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" /> 
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="false" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="true" />
       <application android:label="CamelCase Name" android:theme="@style/STAPPCustomTheme">
             <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YXSIBIDGA......" />
       </application>
</manifest>
```

**Compiled AndroidManifest - Obj Folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall" android:versionName="X.X.x" android:versionCode="XXXYYY">
  <!--Target SDK version should be 25+ in order to ask for permissions in popups.-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <!--Permissions which are requested via popup.-->
  <!--For logging and sensor data writing.-->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <!--For picking photo.-->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <!--For location-->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <!--Permissions granted during installation.-->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <application android:label="CamelCase Name" android:theme="@style/STAPPCustomTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YXSIBIDGA......" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="CamelCase Name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="md***********.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="CamelCase Name" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashNotPowered" android:name="md***********.SplashScreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="Companyname.Utils.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/companynameallinsmall_utils_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <service android:name="md***********.MatchaBackgroundService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Connectivity Plugin Broadcast Receiver" android:name="md***********.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="md***********.MediaPickerActivity" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="md***********.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
   <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="md***********.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.companynameallinsmall.appnameallinsmall" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:exported="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Lint output AndroidManifest.xml:**

> Scanning manifest:
>
> manifest: Error: Can't find API database; API check not performed [LintError]
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:43: Warning: Use '$' instead of '.' for inner
>   classes (or use only lowercase letters in package names); replace
>   "Companyname.Utils.fileProvider" with "Companyname$Utils$fileProvider"
>   [InnerclassSeparator]

```
<provider android:authorities="com.companynameallinsmall.fileProvider"
     android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="Companyname.Utils.fileProvider">
```

> AndroidManifest.xml:33: Error: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug
>   and release builds to automatically assign one [HardcodedDebugMode]

```
<application android:label="CamelCase Name" android:theme="@style/STAPPCustomTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:debuggable="true">
```

> AndroidManifest.xml:33: Warning: On SDK
>   version 23 and up, your app data will be automatically backed up and
>   restored on app install. Consider adding the attribute
>   android:fullBackupContent to specify an @xml resource which configures
>   which files to backup. More info:
>   https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html
>   [AllowBackup]

```
<application android:label="CamelCase Name" android:theme="@style/STAPPCustomTheme"
android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:debuggable="true">
```

> AndroidManifest.xml:33: Warning: App is not indexable by Google
>   Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW
>   intent filter. See issue explanation for more details.
>   [GoogleAppIndexingWarning]

```
<application android:label="CamelCase Name" android:theme="@style/STAPPCustomTheme"  android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:debuggable="true">
```

> ^ 2 errors, 3
>   warnings

[My Installed Android SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJqg5.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.To resolve the first error:

> manifest: Error: Can't find API database; API check not performed
>   [LintError]

You can try to set the `Linking` option to `None`

[image]

2.To resolve the second error:

> AndroidManifest.xml:33: Error: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode;
>   leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign
>   one [HardcodedDebugMode]

You can try to disable Debugging in your code:

For more details, you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#disable-debugging

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debuggable-attribute

**Note:**
If your app still has problems,could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on my side?